# csv reader mismatch in rows values

Tags: python, django, csv, models

I am writing a python script to get data from csv file using python csv reader and loading it into my database. The problem is some rows have only three columns out of twenty four.

My code:

```
spamreader = csv.reader(filename, delimiter='|')
n=0
for row in spamreader:
    n += 1
    if n>2: 
        if len(row)>1:
            if str(row[0]).strip():
                data1 =  str(row[0]).strip() 
            else : 
                data1 = ""
            if str(row[1]).strip():
                data2 =  str(row[1]).strip() 
            else : 
                data2 = ""
            dataload =DataFromCsv(data1=data1,data2=data2,...data24=data24)
            dataload.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   spamreader = csv.reader(filename, delimiter='|')
   next(spamreader) # this skip first line
   for row in spamreader:
        if len(row)>1:
            data = [str(r).strip() if r else "" for r in row]
   ....
```